# Trying to figure out an alternative method for switch statements

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers, switch-statement

I am currently trying to figure out an alternative method for switch statements as the program I have the switch statements are getting really long and confusing. Therefore I thought it would be a good idea to use array of pointers to functions. I am using c++ and qt. But when I try and implement, I am getting the following error.

`cannot convert 'CheckPl::comA' from type 'void (CheckPl::)()' to type 'void (*)()'`

It would be much appreciated if someone would help me out with this or at least point me to correct direction.

Comment: It appears the you cannot convert a pointer to member function of `CheckPI` into a pointer to function. If you [showed some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could probably even help you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] alternative method for switch statements as the program I have the switch statements are getting really long and confusing.

Extract each case block into a separate function; This way, the switch changes from a 10km long function to a dispatch function:

```
void dispatch_function()
{
    switch(x)
    {
    case 1: do_case_1(); break;
    ... 
    case n: do_case_n(); break;
    }
}
```

> Therefore I thought it would be a good idea to use array of pointers to functions.

It's not a good idea (especially, not in the way you went about it - you are solving the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). In C++, when you have a requirement for multiple functions that are called in similar conditions, you have the requirements for an abstract interface.

Your resulting client code should look like this:

```
std::vector<handlers> handlers; // filled with handler instances, one for each case

for(const auto& h: handlers) // replaces switch
    if(h.fits_case(x))       // replaces case statement
    {
        h.do_case(x);        // replaces case block
        break;
    }
```

It follows that your handler classes should inherit from a base class like this:

```
class handler_base
{
    virtual bool fits_case(int x) = 0;
    virtual void do_case(int x) = 0;
}
```

This is easy to understand (in both implementation and client code), it is modular, testable (you can test each case separately) and extensible (if you need a new case you only add the case and add it to the vector); It also doesn't use any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a member function has to be stored in a variable of the appropriate type. A pointer to a member function is not compatible with a pointer to a function.

```
    void (CheckPl::*mptr)() = &CheckPl::comA;
```

A pointer to a member function requires an instance to an object for invocation.

```
    CheckPl c;
    CheckPl *cp = &c;
    (c.*mptr)();
    (cp->*mptr)();
```

The hardest thing to remember about the above syntax is that the extra set of parentheses is required.